# Docusign Credential Login Issue

Tags: docusignapi

Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/credential.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Endpoint: https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/credential.asmx

This morning with the same endpoint, I was able to login.

Comment: Are you able to open the above endpoint in a web browser? If the same code worked before and doesn't work now, it's likely not a code issue but something else. Maybe network connection or firewall?

Comment: Yes I'm able to view the wsdl and see service description

Comment: Do you mean, I need to open firewall for this? This morning I tried from my PC it worked fine but in my VM ie., Office it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to acces the endpoint from the VM using a regular browser? I'm guessing it's a VM/network config issue. If you can access it from the browser, then you don't need to open anything in the firewall. But it seems that you have two different environments and can only access it from one. This isn't a code issue and might be better handled on superuser.com

Comment: Thanks a lot @swbandit, for some reason while intercepting the logs in Fiddler observed that I'm able to hit Credential API, that is when ever Fiddler is open I'm able to interface with Docusign without any issues otherwise it is failing with mentioned error. Not sure of the exact reason but I've work around now to proceed.